# Terraform function lookup within lookup

Tags: amazon-s3, encryption, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to use Terraform function lookup and then lookup to fetch the values and then add into the conditional loop based on the value like below - For creating s3 bucket server side encryption

Below is var.tf

```
 variable "encryption" {
      type = map
      default = {
        "keyMap" = "SSE-S3"
        "kmsType" = "aws-kms"
        "keyNull" = null
      }
    }
```

Now I want to use local.tf with below code to get "SSE-S3" value like below

```
encryption_type = lookup(var.encryption, "default", null) == null ? null : lookup(var.encryption.default, "keyMap", null)
```

Just wonder above my logic will fetch the value for encryption_type is "SSE-S3"

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to lookup `"default"`. The `default` inside a variable definitions is just the default value of that variable. Your current code is actually invalid because a lookup on "default" is never going to work. It's also not clear what your `"keyMap"` lookup is doing, since there is no property in your example named "keyMap".

Your code could be corrected and shortened to the following:

```
encryption_type = lookup(var.encryption, "keyType", null)
```

or just

```
encryption_type = var.encryption["keyType"]
```